# check if all the strings in an array are in a second array

Tags: perl

lets say I have 2 arrays

```
my @one = ("one","two","three","four","five");
my @two = ("three","five");
```

How can I tell if ALL the elements in the second array are in the first?

Comment: Are the arrays guaranteed to be sets of unique elements, or could you have for instance `@one = ("one", "one", "one", "two", "one" ...)` ?

Comment: please clarify your requirements.  Do you consider all elements of `('a', 'a', 'b')` to be in `('a', 'b')`?

Comment: yes, I am only concerned that all the 'file' in a file array have arrived when compared to a list of all the files in my rcv dir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my %one = map { $_ => 1 } @one;
if (grep($one{$_}, @two) == @two) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to perl. Can you walk me through what these lines are doing.

Comment: #1 creates a hash. An element is created in the hash for each value in `@one`. The value from the array is used as the key in the hash.

Comment: #2 counts the number of elements in `@two` that are keys in `%one`. Then, it compares that count to the number of elements in `@two`.

Comment: This solution might not be suited now that the OP has clarified that at least one of the arrays can contain duplicate members.

Comment: @pilcrow, Works fine with duplicate members in either/both arrays.

Comment: My solution is O(N). Axeman's and Joel Berger's solutions are O(N^2). My solution scales better.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way to solve.

```
my %hash;
undef @hash{@two};  # add @two to keys %hash 
delete @hash{@one}; # remove @one from keys %hash 
print !%hash;       # is there anything left?
```

I stole the idea from this [perlmonks node](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=997026)

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;

my @one = ("one","two","three","four","five");
my @two = ("three","five");

my %seen_in_one = map {$_ => 1} @one;

if (my @missing = grep {!$seen_in_one{$_}} @two) {
    print "The following elements are missing: @missing";
} else {
    print "All were found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, not sure its any better than ikegami's. Still TIMTOWTDI

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/first/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/all/;

my @one = ("one","two","three","four","five");
my @two = ("three","five");

if ( all { my $find = $_; first { $find eq $_ } @one } @two ) {
  print "All \@two found in \@one\n";
}
```

Comment: This is essentially @Axeman's solution.  Smart match is going to be faster than first, but they're both O(M*N).  I guess yours is O(M/2*N) (on average, `first` will only have to search half the array) but the slower performance of `first` vs `~~` will negate that.

Comment: yeah, as my post may have indicated, I started down the List::(More)Util(s) path and posted it for "completeness"; I'm not surprised that its not "the best". Still as my solution was posted before @axemans's I claim that his is essentially like mine :-P

Answer (score 0):

Since 5.10, the smart match operator will do that.

```
my $verdict = !grep { not $_ ~~ @one } @two;
```

Or with [**`List::MoreUtils::all`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils#all):

```
my $verdict = all { $_ ~~ @one } @two;
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error when i try the first one. It says it's near "$_ ~~". I'm using perl 5.8.8

Comment: @Bill ... which is before 5.10

Comment: This solution, while elegant code, is O(M*N).  Which is to say it has to do `@one * @two` operations.  If `@one` and `@two` both have 5 elements, that's 25 operations.  If they have 10 it's 100 operations.  20 and it's 400.  Don't use it for anything but very small lists.